# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel in CSOM

Tags: ssl, sharepoint, server, tls1.2, csom

Getting below error, Please suggest any solution.

**The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel** on windows server2012 R2. at clientContext.ExecuteQuery.

Code for CSOM SharePoint:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                   | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                   | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
                   | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("test.SharePoint.Com"))
            {

                try
                {
                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;

                    ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
                    SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
                    foreach (char c in "test")
                        securePassword.AppendChar(c);

                    ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("test.com", securePassword);
                    Web web = ctx.Web;
                    ctx.Load(web);
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery(); //The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
                    Console.WriteLine("The web site title: " + web.Title);
                    Console.Read();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try setting your project to 4.72 .net framework version. (or even 4.8 if you have it installed).

Comment: tried on the updated framework still not working.

Comment: Same code with ,Powershell script gives below error::

Comment: Error Getting Site Title: Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The request was aborted: Could not create S
SL/TLS secure channel."